# Reading hexadecimal values from file and displaying them in C

Tags: c, hex, fgets

I have a key.hex file which contains:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
```

as hexadecimal values. I try to read them and immediately print them:

```
unsigned char key[16];
FILE *secretkey;
secretkey = fopen("key.hex", "r+");
fgets(key, 16, secretkey);
int j = 0;
for(j = 0; j < sizeof(key) ; j++) {
    printf("%02x ", key[j]);
}
```

However, as I get the following output:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 00 80 d2 73 b7
```

Why the output does not correspond to the content of the file?

Comment: You read 15 ***characters*** into `key`, not the full line, and you read it as a ***string*** not as separate integers.

Comment: In a typical ASCII environment `0a` is line feed (`LF` or `\n`), which terminates your `fgets` call, so you don't read the remaining bytes. Use `fread` instead of `fgets`.

Comment: Are these numbers stored as text or as binary values?

Comment: So, if 0a is equal to line feed, what could be the way to make it work properly?

Comment: Use `fread` like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/D6JnNHA4OPZyZ7Vd)

Comment: If this is a binary file, you should open it in binary mode `"rb+"`.

Comment: @user694733 Good point, did not notice that is relevant in BLUEPIXY code. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Paul R.:
In a typical ASCII environment `0a` is line feed (`LF` or `\n`), which terminates your fgets call, so you don't read the remaining bytes.
Use fread instead of fgets.

E.g.
(most relevant lines from code linked in comment by BLUEPIXY, which is a complete demonstrator):

```
secretkey = fopen("key.hex", "r+b");
fread(key, 1, sizeof key, secretkey);
```

*(This compiles an answer from two comments, each of which would be a decent answer. I offer to delete if any of the two authors makes their own answer and asks me to.)*

Answer (score 1):

You said that the file contains these hexadecimal values:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
```

So the file contains precisely 16 bytes: the first has value `0x00`, the second has value `0x01`, etc.

This is what's known as a *binary file*.  It is very much not a text file.  There are almost no ordinary, printable characters in that file.  If we were to print that file to the screen, we would see weird glyphs and garbage, or perhaps nothing.

But the `fgets` function is intended for reading one line of *text* from a text file.  Specifically, it reads characters up to and including the end-of-line indication.  On Unix/Linux systems, the end-of-line indication is the linefeed character.  In ASCII, the linefeed character has the character code `0x0a`.  Also, since the `fgets` function is intended to work with text, it converts the text it reads into a C string, by appending a null byte (`0x00` or `'\0'`) at the end of the output buffer.

So what happened was that `fgets` read only the first 11 characters from the file, up to and including the `0A`, and wrote those characters plus the terminating null character to the `key` array.  So it filled in only the first 12 cells of the array.  The last 4 characters retained whatever uninitialized garbage values the array contained when you first defined it.  (In this case, it looks like they were `80`, `d2`, `73`, and `b7`.)

But what you really want to do in this case, it looks like, is read 16 raw bytes, without assuming that they're text, without looking for a newline, without null-terminating the result.  That's a very different requirement, but it turns out there's another standard library function which does exactly what you want: `fread`.

So rewrite your code like this:

```
FILE *secretkey;
secretkey = fopen("key.hex", "rb");
if(secretkey == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s\n", "key.hex");
    exit(1);
}
int r = fread(key, 1, 16, secretkey);
if(r != 16) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error reading key: read %d chars, expected %d\n", r, 16);
    exit(1);
}
int j;
for(j = 0; j < sizeof(key) ; j++) {
    printf("%02x ", key[j]);
}
```

You'll notice that I've also added code to check that `fread` did actually read 16 bytes as expected.  Also I've added code to check that the `fopen` call succeeded in opening the "key.hex" file.  Also I've changed the `fopen` call to open the file in binary mode (`"rb"`), and delete the `+` modifier, which you probably don't want.

As a side note, if you want to do better error handling, when opening a file fails, it's always a good idea to print a more descriptive error message indicating *why* the file couldn't be opened:

```
if(secretkey == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s: %s\n", "key.hex", strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

To do that you'll also have to include the header files `<string.h>` for the `strerror()` function, and `<errno.h>` for the `errno` value.